# Coalesce нескольких значений

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется две таблицы
dge

| id | name | ext_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Автомобили | IAB11 |
| 2 | Автозапчасти | IAB12 |

и cr

| id | type | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Видео-посты ОК | IAB11 |
| 2 | Видео-посты ОК | IAB11, IAB12 |

Мне необходимо заменить значения в таблице cr в поле category, на значения из справочника dge (поле name). Т.е. вместо category в cr подставить name из dge. Мой запрос работал , пока в поле category не стало приходить несколько значений , через запятую. Я не могу понять, как мне заменять значения, когда их несколько. Мой запрос не отрабатывает

Желаемый результат:

| id | type | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Видео-посты ОК | Автомобили, Автозапчасти |

```
select cr.id,cr.type,COALESCE(dge.name, cr.category) AS category
from  creative cr
 LEFT JOIN dic_glossary_element dge ON dge.ext_code = cr.category
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select cr.id, cr.type, 
  (
    select string_agg("name", ', ') 
    from dic_glossary_element 
    where ext_code = any (string_to_array(cr.category, ', '))
  ) as category
from creative cr;
```

Вариант 2

```sql
select t.id, "type", string_agg("name", ', ') category
from 
(
  select id, "type", 
         unnest(string_to_array(category, ', ')) ext_code 
  from creative
) as t
join dic_glossary_element using (ext_code)
group by 1, 2;
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!! Вы очень помогли))) все оказывается не так сложно! Вы гений)))